# Missing android.util.Log class file

Tags: java, android, logging, intellij-idea

I installed the latest version of Android SDK but when I try `import android.util.Log` I see that this class is nonexistent. I don't have any ideas. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Are sure your project sdk is set to android and not java?

Comment: @Naveed, Yes, I'm sure. But no results. 
Screen: [click](http://storage3.static.itmages.com/i/15/0706/h_1436207407_1846267_b81c056242.png)

Comment: Gradle resync gives no change?

Comment: @404notfound, yes. I have solved this problem. See below first answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! Trouble is solved! Everything was very simple.

Step by step:

1. Open `Auto Import` settings
2. Switch off `Optimize imports on the fly`
3. Remove class in `Exclude list`

Screenshot:

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Try Cleaning your project. Build > Project Clean